# How to filter dropdownlistfor according to what has selected in first dropdownlist in asp mvc?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, html.dropdownlistfor

I am working on a asp.net mvc project and I need to filter dropdownlist according to what user has selected first dropdownlist

This is my first dropdownlist in view:

```
<div class="form-group">
   @Html.LabelFor(m => m.BuildDefinitionName, "Build Definition name", new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
   <div class="col-md-10">
      @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.BuildDefinitionName, new SelectList(Model.BuildData.Select(x => x.Key), "BuildInfo"), "select", new { @class = "form-control" })
   </div>
</div>
```

and this is my second dropdownlist:

```
<div class="form-group">
   @Html.LabelFor(m => m.CurrentBuildNumber, "Current Build", new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
   <div class="col-md-10">
      @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CurrentBuildNumber, new SelectList(Model.BuildData
           .Where(x=>x.Key == "#BuildDefinitionName")
           .Select(y => y.Value), "BuildInfo"), "select", new { @class = "form-control" })
   </div>
</div>
```

I have a dictionary that key is string (what the user should chose first dropdown ) and value is IEnumerable ( what it should be filtered by the first dropdown selection).

I am so thanksful for solving my problem.

after applying the answer : [image: screenshot one]

[image: screenshot2]

[image: screenshot3]

[image: screenshot4]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use jquery to modify the second dropdown list.

1. In your 2nd dropdown list, you need to put all the data of `Model.BuildData`. So, in your controller, be sure to provide all the records because we will be filtering on client-side.

```
public ActionResult ControllerName(){
   var yourModel = new yourModel();

   // Add all the entries to Build Data, we're going to filter it with jquery
   yourModel.BuildData = db.BuildData.ToList();

   return View(yourModel);
}
```

2. In your 2nd dropdown list, we need to put a data attribute on the html. For this example, we're rendering it manually, replace your 2nd dropdown list with the HTML below.

```
<div class="form-group">
   @Html.LabelFor(m => m.CurrentBuildNumber, "Current Build", new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
   <div class="col-md-10">
      <select id="CurrentBuildNumber" name="CurrentBuildNumber" class="form-control">
         @foreach(var selectItem in Model.BuildData){
            <option data-filter="@selectItem.Key" value="@selectItem.Value">
               @selectITEM.Value
            </option>
         }
      </select>
   </div>
</div>
```

3. Lastly, we need to add an onchange script to the 1st dropdown list that would filter the 2nd dropdownlist.

The code below will loop through all the options in the 2nd dropdown list, and if its data-attribute doesn't match with the selected value, it will hide it.

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
      $(document).on("change","#BuildDefinitionName",function(){
         var selected = $(this).val();
         $("#CurrentBuildNumber").find("options").each(function(){
            if($(this).data("filter")==selected){

               // if data-filter is the same as the selected value, show it
               $(this).show();
            }else{

               // if it doesn't match, hide
               $(this).hide();
            }
         });
      });
   });
</script>
```

Comment: @mah If you encountered any errors, please include a screenshot of the error and a screenshot of the html output. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, Now I have 2 problem, 1: foreach title that I select for first dropdown, it does not filter and it just shows one row (maybe first row), 2: it does not show my value content, I attached both screenshots.

Comment: @mah Thanks for the update, will you include a screenshot of the html in dev tools of the 2nd dropdown list, after you applied the answer?

Comment: sure, I attached the screenshot

Comment: @mah I need the html result in the browser, right click > inspect element. Thanks!

Comment: I solved the second problem: because the value was ienumerable i should use another foreach  inside the   foreach(var selectItem in Model.BuildData).